# Most recent message on top in a Gmail conversation

Tags: gmail

Just migrated from Outlook and I have problems with the emails order in a conversation.
I would prefer having the last email on top.

Anybody knows of an app that can be used?

Comment: In practical terms, the only way you're going to be able to do that is to interact with Gmail using a POP and/or IMAP client.

Answer (score 8):

While I understand your confusion when first arriving at Gmail, may I suggest not changing it, even if you find a way? Many features in Gmail are specifically designed to make chronological reading more convenient.

One of the reasons to use reverse-chronological ordering is because the newest email also had all the previous replies in it, so you only read one email (bottom to top). But in Gmail, duplicate information is hidden, meaning each email only contains the text unique to that letter. You can read top to bottom without duplication, and in the order of the conversation. When you return to the email later to look at new replies, the previously read emails default to hidden, so they do not clutter up your screen.

Because of this heavy optimization on chronological reading, while it may be possible to find a plugin that alters this behavior, it will also almost certainly reduce the efficiency with which you deal with mail. I recommend you spend a week or two with Gmail before you immediately seek to improve their UI.

Comment: I've used Gmail for years and I always need a button to allow me to read mail in reversed order (my issue is detailed here http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28595/gmail-conversation-view-order-cannot-be-reverted)

Comment: Thank you for describing how you feel you are more efficient reading email. Others may be more efficient reading email in ways other than the way you are most efficient.

Comment: I didn't tell him he should never change it; only that he should give it a try before asking immediately to change it, since Gmail has unique usability enhancements to chronological ordering that many other clients do not.

Comment: I've uses gmail for years and hate the order from oldest to newest in conversations. I recently started using this chrome extension to change the order from newest to oldest in conversations and it works great!
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-reverse-conversatio/kfgepjmmgamniaefbjlbacahkjjnjoaa?hl=en

Comment: @Laurens, why not create that as an answer to the question. Don't reply to me... make your own answer.

Comment: Google got it wrong on this one. Newest first is the De facto standard in email because it is more efficient. The real problem is when holding a conversation between Gmail and (say) Outlook users: every other email is in a different order. So, they either need to get with the standard, or find a way to smartly handle conversations in that kind of mixed environment

Answer (score 0):

[This app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-reverse-conversatio/kfgepjmmgamniaefbjlbacahkjjnjoaa?hl=en) reverses the order Gmail renders threads. It uses CSS only; in fact, you could replace the app with a client CSS override too. If you prefer the safety of just installing the CSS, you can check out their [gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/redribbon/gmail-reverse) for the plugin and put the CSS found there into your favorite CSS override plugin (example: [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha))

I prefer it in chronological order; I think Google improved email clients forever with their smart eliding of reply text. But different strokes for different folks.